# dplyr filtering with the %in% operator for two dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes.

The first is my main pool, and the second is a "list" of names that I want to filter on.

main:

```
aaa   bbb   ccc
dog   1     2
cat   2     4
dog   1     2 
dog   1     2  
cat   3     2 
snake 1     5
snake 3     2
```

list1 (currently in a dataframe)

```
aaa
dog
cat
```

I want to use dplyr::filter and the %in% operator to subset the main pool:

```
sub <- main %>% filter(aaa %in% list1)
```

I thought the above would work, but it's creating a 0 row dataframe.

Comment: You may need to change it to `aaa %in% list$aaa` since `list` is a data frame.

Comment: Also, it's better never to name anything `list` since that is a commonly used function's name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Richard's suggestion worked!

```
aaa %in% list1$aaa
```